# Vuforia how to place persistent models in the world

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

I am using Vuforia and Unity to do AR. So far I have gone through the ImageTarget example, and am able to see the teapot using my Samsung Galaxy S4. I've also managed to overlay some UI elements on the screen.

Now, I'm trying to place a persistent 3d object (capsule for example) in the world.

However, when I place a capsule say, next to the teapot, I see only a white screen when I start the android app.

Why is this so? How can I resolve this?

My scene hierachy is like this

> ARCamera
>
> Directional Light
>
> ImageTargetChips
>
> ImageTargetStones
>
> Canvas <-- for UI overlay
>
> EventSystem
>
> Capsule <-- adding this into the world causes screen to turn white

Even if I shift Capsule to under ARCamera, I only see white when I start up the app.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked the position of the capsule and the size? It could be that your capsule coordinates just appear to be in on the Image.

Comment: Hi @AugmentedJacob the capsule is really small, compared to the rest. It works when I put a model into the scene. So this is quite strange.

Comment: Oh. So your problem is solved? If it is, feel free to answer your own question so others may be able to see it if they come across the same.

Comment: No it isn't resolved... Somehow unity basic models like cube and capsule don't really work. Probably a bug in Vuforia eyewear sdk?

Comment: It's hard to tell. Could you upload a screenshot of your Unity screen and maybe something else that could be affecting it like the ARCamera -> Inspector

Answer (score 0):

You have to learn about the **Unity hierarchy**. Everything, i.e., 3D objects, image, audio, etc., i.e **content associated** to specific image target must be **Hierarchically child of ImageTarget.**

---

**Here, you need to put your 3DObject (Capsule) inside the image target (Stones/Chips).**

Like

```
> +ARCamera
>
> -ImageTargetChips
>
>          Teapot
>          Capsule
```

---

And then **adjust the position & Scale of capsule (3D Object)**

Your 3D object must be in a camera view:

```
eg. Position of camera:       x:0 y:0 z:0

    Position of image target: x:0 y:0 z:-60
```

Here, **Z axis is "Depth"**